# how to force landscape mode for dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout

imagine your activity is (forced!) in portrait mode and you'll show an dialog from there, but in landscape mode (because it's containing view is larger than screen width), how will you do that?

I think the screen-orientation of a dialog depends on it's hosting activity/service.

Is there still a way? (e.g. force default orientation of dialog view over it's layout xml-file?)

Comment: Please read my question again. My activity is already in portrait mode. What I do need is to have a dialog, started from that activity, but in landscape mode...

Comment: i guess you need to first put your activity in landscape (what's the relation with the xml layout file?)

Comment: That's the problem. The layout in my activity is strongly designed for portrait mode, so I can't switch. Another idea was to pre-define the screenOrientation in dialog-views xml layout file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how do you define the screenOrientation in an xml layout file ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Any solution for this ??

Answer (score 4):

If you are under `DialogFragment` Use
 on dialog create       `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`
 and on dialog dissmiss        `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);`
if you don't want activity recreate add also
  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
other way you will have to handle activity being recreated